# Object object ngFor angular 9/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to learn Angular 9 the past days and wanted to re-do a pokemon app.

The problem I'm having right now is that when I try to loop through the pokemon array, it displays [object Object] on the screen.

Now I know that the ngFor can only iterate through Arrays, and that's why I am having this problem, but I can't seem to solve it.

Here's the code:

pokemon.service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PokemonService {
  private pokemonsUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPokemons() {
    return this.http.get(this.pokemonsUrl);
  }
}
```

pokemon.component:

```
 pokemons: any[] = [];
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private pokemonService: PokemonService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pokemonService.getPokemons().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.pokemons = data['results'];
        console.log(this.pokemons);
      },
      (err: any) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('all done getting pokemons')
    );
  }
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="pokemons">
  <div *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons">
    {{pokemon}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's does `console.log(this.pokemons)` print?

Comment: Can you show what's the response type? If it's array of objects you need to specify the property e.g. `{{pokemon.name}}` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears each element of the array is an object with properties `name` and `url`.

[image]

You could access the properties directly in the template. Try the following

```html
<div *ngIf="pokemons">
  <div *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons">
    {{ pokemon.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```